# How can we pull function definitions into a type class, instead of a reference

Tags: haskell

I have provided some code below that demonstrates the basic concept of a project. I have modules that are set up as interfaces; I implement the interfaces to build modules. In the example below, I built an `Alpha`.

```
type Ticker = String
type Shares = Int
type Price = Float
data Insight = Down | Flat | Up deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
type Target = Float

data Universe = Universe {generateUniverse :: [(Ticker, Price)] -> [(Ticker, Price)]}
data Alpha = Alpha {generateInsights :: [(Ticker, Price)] -> [(Ticker, Insight)]}
data Portfolio = Portfolio {generateTargets :: [(Ticker, Insight)] -> [(Ticker, Target)]}
data Execution = Execution {generateOrders :: [(Ticker, Price)] -> [(Ticker, Target)] -> [(Ticker, Shares)]}

convert :: (Ticker, Price) -> (Ticker, Insight)
convert (t, p)
  | p < 500 = (t, Down)
  | p == 500 = (t, Flat)
  | p > 500 = (t, Up)

split :: [(Ticker, Price)] -> [(Ticker, Insight)]
split xs = foldr (\tp acc -> (convert tp):acc) [] xs

splitAlpha :: Alpha
splitAlpha = Alpha {
  generateInsights = split
  }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let
    alpha = splitAlpha
  print (generateInsights alpha [("TSLA", 500.0), ("RKT", 10.0), ("AMC", 750)])
```

How can I compress my definition of `splitAlpha` so that there is not as much nesting in the definition of `generateInsights`? I have attempted the example below...

```
convert :: (Ticker, Price) -> (Ticker, Insight)
convert (t, p)
  | p < 500 = (t, Down)
  | p == 500 = (t, Flat)
  | p > 500 = (t, Up)

splitAlpha :: Alpha
splitAlpha = Alpha {
  generateInsights xs = foldr (\tp acc -> (convert tp):acc) [] xs
  }
```

and recieved this error:

```
ghci> :cmd return $ unlines [":l itk", ":main"]
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( itk.hs, interpreted )

itk.hs:23:20: error: parse error on input `xs'
   |
23 |   generateInsights xs = foldr (\tp acc -> (convert tp):acc) [] xs
   |                    ^^
Failed, no modules loaded.

<interactive>:60:53: error:
    * Variable not in scope: main :: IO a0
    * Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)
```

Comment: `generateInsights = \xs -> ...`.

Comment: Actually this might be worth bringing up as a GHC feature request. In the spirit of “`data` is the better OO-class pendant”, it would certainly be good to support full function declaration syntax in record builders (even though in many cases, like this one, it's trivial to avoid it with lambdas etc.). This would raise some hairy questions though, not just WRT parsing but more fundamentally stuff like whether recursive definitions should be allowed, how the name lookup would work then, etc..

Comment: I suggested adding this once, informally. I can't find it but I think it's a sensible feature to add

Comment: [This has been a sore point for almost a decade.](https://twitter.com/aisamanra/status/519721321681268736) (Probably more than a decade, but this is the first documented solution attempt I know of.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a lambda expression, so:

```
splitAlpha :: Alpha
splitAlpha = Alpha {
  generateInsights = \xs -> foldr (\tp acc -> (convert tp):acc) [] xs
  }
```

In this specific case however, this is just a mapping function, so you can work with:

```
splitAlpha :: Alpha
splitAlpha = Alpha {
  generateInsights = map convert
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Willem Van Onsem wrote, this example is super easy because the whole thing boils down to `generateInsights = map convert`. But more generally, it wouldn't be so easy. Lambda syntax only works for single-clause functions with no guards

```
splitAlpha = Alpha
  { generateInsights = \xs -> ...
  }
```

More generally, you can always use `let` to have a proper definition-scope in which you can define any function *locally* with full syntax available, but avoiding to populate any other namespace:

```
splitAlpha = Alpha
  { generateInsights
       = let gi xs = foldr (\tp acc -> (convert tp):acc) [] xs
         in gi
  }
```